# How to catch such an error with jest and testing-library/react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs

Simply saying I want to assert clicking on this button without onClick prop will result in an error(I know this is a silly case but this is just a rough simplification). But unfortunately I cannot catch this error, no matter how I tried.

**The pseudocode looks like this:**

*Element.js:*

```html
const Element = ({ onClick }) => (
<button onClick={() => onClick('test')}>Test</button>)
);
```

*Element.test.js*

```js
it('triggers on click callback', () => {
    const wrapper = render(<Element />);

    expect(userEvent.click(wrapper.getByTestId('test'))).toThrowError();
  });
```

I receive 3 console.error statements: "console.error Error: Uncaught [TypeError: onClick is not a function]"

and a

```
   expect(received).toThrowError()
    Received function did not throw
```

This doesn't make much sense to me. Please help me find a solution or at least clarify what is happening

Comment: Core `try catch` block will work

Comment: The error is telling you what's wrong: "`onClick` is not a function".  It's the `render` call that's throwing because you're not passing in a value for `onClick`.

Comment: Guys, that is absolute clear. The question is how to catch such an error with a test

Comment: Most adequate solution I found is not to render button if it doesn't have proper handler. But question about catching such errors still remains

Answer (score 2):

You can't catch & assert errors that originate in event handlers using `jest` & `testing-library`.

You can use `expect.toThrow` from `jest` to assert errors are thrown from a function or a React `render`, but sadly not for what you want.

`jest` has no way of catching errors coming out of event handlers, as they happen in a separate thread to the main execution, so they won't propagate back up to your test (might not be using the correct terminology here, but hope you get the idea). For the same reason, React `ErrorBoundary` cannot catch and deal with these kind of errors.

All I can suggest is perhaps catching and logging the error in the handler, then assert that `.log()` was called using a spy in your test.

Here are some discussions/ documentation on this subject that you may find useful:

https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library/issues/1068

https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library/issues/624

https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is my (hackish) Solution for that Problem:

**1. jest.config.ts -> add these lines at the end to make the actual process object available in tests**

```
const actualProcess = process;
(process as any).actual = () => actualProcess;
```

**Then in your test before triggering the event remove listeners and catch the error:**

```
// handle unhandledRejection
const proc = process.actual() as NodeJS.Process;
let unhandledRejectionError: AxiosError;
const existingListeners = proc.listeners('unhandledRejection');
proc.removeAllListeners('unhandledRejection');
proc.on('unhandledRejection', (reason: AxiosError) => {
  unhandledRejectionError = reason;
});
```

**At the end of your test reattach the listeners so other tests still fail when error ahppens:**

```
// Re-add the original listeners after handling
existingListeners.forEach((listener) => {
  proc.on('unhandledRejection', listener);
});
```